# How to change name on array in JSON using node.js and express

Tags: node.js, express

I have a [API](http://194.141.118.43:3000/?id=16) and to change the name on index of array from 0 to some name.

They are two array's under ardaforecast and I want to change the first array with name **data** and second array with name **details**.

```
    // Create express app
var express = require("express")
var app = express()
var mysql = require('mysql')
var express = require("express")
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())

// Server port
var HTTP_PORT = 3000

var pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: '192.168.0.1',
  user: 'UName',
  port: '3333',
  password: 'Pass',
  database: 'dbName'
});

var ardaforecast = '';


app.route('/')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    // omitted
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*', 'Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    const id = req.query.id;

    pool.query(`CALL Get_Alert_levels_Station(${id});`, function (error, result) {
      if (error)
      return res.status(500).json({ error: "Грешна заявка. Опитай отново !"})
      ardaforecast = result;
      res.json({ ardaforecast })
    });
  });

// Start server
app.listen(HTTP_PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port %PORT%".replace("%PORT%", HTTP_PORT))
});

pool.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log(err.code); // 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR'
});

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.status(404);
});
```

Comment: Can you add the data and what is the expected data? I can see the response from API and there is an array ardaforecast? What do you want to do?

Comment: Inside in ardaforecast array have other two array's. I want to rename it from 0 and 1 to data and details ..

Comment: You can't change the keys of arrays to string values.  You might need object to do, iterate through the array and for both the index add values to the key.

Comment: Can I get example how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of doing this will be creating a list of keys you want to add and iterate through the array `ardaforecast`:

```js
const data = {"ardaforecast":[[{"Dt":"2021-07-22T23:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-23T02:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-23T05:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-23T08:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-23T11:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-23T14:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-23T17:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-23T20:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-23T23:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-24T02:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-24T05:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-24T08:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-24T11:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-24T14:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-24T17:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-24T20:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-24T23:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-25T02:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-25T05:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-25T08:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-25T11:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-25T14:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-25T17:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-25T20:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-25T23:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-26T02:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-26T05:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-26T08:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-26T11:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-26T14:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-26T17:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-26T20:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-26T23:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-27T02:00:00.000Z","AL":1},{"Dt":"2021-07-27T05:00:00.000Z","AL":1}],{"fieldCount":0,"affectedRows":0,"insertId":0,"serverStatus":34,"warningCount":0,"message":"","protocol41":true,"changedRows":0}]};

const newData = {};
const keys = ['data', 'details']; // you can change it or add new keys 
data.ardaforecast.forEach((el, i) => {
      newData[keys[i]] = el;
});

console.log(newData);
```